# Angular custom Directive ngClass object not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a custom directive for toggling password visibility.
My directive Code:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPwdVisMng]'
})
export class PwdVisMngDirective {
  shown: boolean = false;
  eyeClass = {
    "ui": true,
    "eye": true,
    "slash": false,
    "link": true,
    "icon": true,
  }
  eyeSlashClass = {
    "ui": true,
    "eye": true,
    "slash": true,
    "link": true,
    "icon": true,
  }
  pwdClass = this.eyeClass;

  constructor() { }
  toggle(id) {
    if (!this.shown) {
      this.shown = !this.shown;
      this.pwdClass = this.eyeSlashClass;
      document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('type', 'text');
    } else {
      this.shown = !this.shown;
      this.pwdClass = this.eyeClass;
      document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('type', 'password');
    }
  }
}
```

and I use it in a component template and the HTML code is

```
<div class="ui center aligned grid container">
  <h2>Chitchat</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ui five wide computer eight wide tablet  fifteen wide mobile column segment">
      <form class="ui form" method="post" novalidate>
        <h3>Reset Password</h3>       
        <div class="ui field">
          <div class="ui link icon input">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <i appPwdVisMng [ngClass]="pwdClass" (click)="toggle('pwd')"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="ui primary large button" type="submit">Change Password</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What my problem is, that I have a ngClass object in my directive and I use it in the component HTML code. But the classes are not applying.
I don't know why, and I need to know how to do this or, is there any standard way to do this?

I also don't have any objects and methods in component related to this part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the directive from feature module or root module .. if feature module import common module

Comment: Yeah I already did import the common module.

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. I tried to have the ngClass object inside the component class, it worked. But in directive class not working